# How to access specific column totals for pivot table in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a very trivial question but I am struggling to find a answer to this online.

How do I "access" a pivot table `grand total` for a given column.

For instance I have the pivot table `"pivottable1"`.

```
Customer   Product Code   Sum of price
   .   
   .             .
   .                           . 
 GRAND TOTAL                   $5000
```

So in this example I want to copy the `$5000` into another cell.

The pivot table is dynamic and will change length.

I want to say for a given column Sum of price, take the `grand total` and copy it to another cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Notes:**

- Will print the value to `A1`
- Change the Field Name accordingly
- Will work for Columns.
- More info here [Referencing Pivot Table Range](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/)

**Try:**

```
Sub tst()

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = .PivotFields("Sum of Sum").DataRange.End(xlDown).Value

End With

End Sub
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: That does work but it gives me only the last column, how can I choose a different column and also I want to copy that value to another cell not open it up with a message box, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Give it a try:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lngRows As Long, lngColumns As Long, lngGT As Long

    With Sheet1.PivotTables(1).DataBodyRange
        lngRows = .Rows.Count
        lngColumns = .Columns.Count
        lngGT = .Cells(1).Offset(lngRows - 1, lngColumns - 1)
    End With

    Sheet1.Range("E11").Value = lngGT
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your post - which line is highlighted when the error appears? Either way, I see Mikku already gave you a correct answer so I'm glad it all worked out for you.